# Scrapy/requests simulate XHR

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, scrapy

I am trying to grab the reviews from https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60763-d2173604-Reviews-Dream_Downtown-New_York_City_New_York.html, and it seems like the AJAX request I need when you click more on reviews is https://www.tripadvisor.com/OverlayWidgetAjax?Mode=EXPANDED_HOTEL_REVIEWS&metaReferer=Hotel_Review. How do I get the xhr post request so I can correctly parse all of the data? Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

def parse(self, response):
    url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/OverlayWidgetAjax?Mode=EXPANDED_HOTEL_REVIEWS&metaReferer=Hotel_Review'
    headers = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
                'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
                'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'}
    req = scrapy.Request(url,method='POST',body='{"filters": []}',headers=headers,callback=self.parse_me)
    yield req
def parse_me(self,response):
    print(response.body)
```

Also I noticed this only contains the listings that have a 'more' option, so to get all reviews would my best bet be to do something like this:

```
if 'more' is present:
     do xhr request
else:
   pass
```

If possible I would also like the solution for requests as I am new to scrapy and still have not found the corresponding answer for the requests module which I am pretty familiar with. I always resort to using selenium which I want to get away from. Thanks.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: @PeterHenell I am trying to figure out how to bring in the xhr post request so that I can get the review data from there instead of using selenium to click more and then reading from the page source. I am not entirely sure how to do this and the current headers gives me a 404

Answer (score 0):

So I have started from [this URL](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60763-d224214-Reviews-The_Bryant_Park_Hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html), right?

As far as I can see, each review has a title that is clickable; it has a URL, that leads to the full review. For example, clicking “Modern,Clean,Excellent Staff!” I get the URL:

https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g60763-d224214-r470551868-The_Bryant_Park_Hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html#CHECK_RATES_CONT

So you can simply loop on the wrappers to get the URL of each review's title as well.

This is one way.

---

Another way is when I click "More" and Inspect in Network > XHR, I get this URL:

https://www.tripadvisor.com/OverlayWidgetAjax?Mode=EXPANDED_HOTEL_REVIEWS&metaReferer=Hotel_Review&reviews=470551868,470078957,469616995,469417970

Note, this has more than one review - notice the numbers at the end. We can have one or more. For example, to get the same above review by keeping only one number:

https://www.tripadvisor.com/OverlayWidgetAjax?Mode=EXPANDED_HOTEL_REVIEWS&metaReferer=Hotel_Review&reviews=470551868

Okay, the question now is from where can we get this last number? You can find it in the attribute data-reviewid   and you can even find it in the URL above in the first way.